# Clear app data programatically in Android

Tags: android, webview

In KitKat and above, this code works perfectly:

```
ActivityManager manager = ((ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE));
manager.clearApplicationUserData();
```

It wipes all of the app settings, any internal databases, webview caches, etc. It's great.

I want to write some code that will do this same thing for users with versions below KitKat.

I've tried:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("pm clear com.example.myapp");
```

That doesn't work.

Also tried:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

That doesn't work.

Also tried a bunch of `clearCache()`, `clearHistory()`, `.setAppCacheEnabled(false)`, etc on the webview. No luck.

Basically, my biggest problem is the webview seems to still be caching data (ie. if I've logged into a site through the webview, I want to be able to delete that session permanently and log the user out). Nothing I do (except `clearApplicationUserData`) is able to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: your edit should be posted as answer (answering own question is perfectly fine) and then you should mark own answer as accepted so others will know your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this problem I did this to fix it:

```
                CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(activity);
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
                cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
                syncManager.stopSync();
                syncManager.sync();
```